# Rails - Require/Permit Params does not allow nested arrays and objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rest, parameters

I am sending a nested object to my controller and print the params but it does not let objects or arrays pass through the filter.

Here is my permit function:

```
      params.require(:review).permit(:review_text, :user_id,
                                     questions: [ :text, :rate ],
                                     :course => [:code, :name, :ects, :type])
```

Here is the data I try to send

```
{
    "course": {
        "code": "CS 101",
        "name": "Introduction to Programming",
        "ects": "6",
        "type": "Lecture"
    },
    "user_id": "604a9382777a83b08307c7e8",
    "review_text": "a very useful course",
    "questions": [
        {
            "text": "course was very nice",
            "rate": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

When I print the review_params, it prints out {"review_text"=>"a very useful course", "user_id"=>"604a9382777a83b08307c7e8"}

Comment: `require(:review)` means `review` MUST be present, and your example doesn't show it, so I guess it's not what you send

Comment: Thank you :) It was a rookie mistake and I thought it was okay since it understood some of the params :)